# EJB3 - @Column(insertable="false") question

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, toplink-essentials, ora-01400

I'm building a J2SE application with EJB3 and an Oracle Express Edition DB.

My problem is like that - I set an EntityBean in my project which matches a table in the DB. The table contains a column which is not nullable and has a **default value**. All I want is that when persisting a new data to this table using the EJB, the column's value will get its default value. This is how I set it in the project:

```
//holds user's first name
@Basic(optional = true)
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = true, nullable = false)
private String m_firstName;
```

I also set it in the ORM.XML file:

```
    <basic name="firstName">
        <column name="FIRST_NAME" insertable="false" updatable="true" nullable="false"/>
    </basic>
```

But for some reason, when creating a new EntityBean and not setting the first name field, and then trying to persist it, i get the following exception:

```
Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b60e-fcs (12/23/2008))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TSDB"."USERS"."FIRST_NAME")
```

Which means that the persistence manager tries to insert the first name field although I told it not to.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the following annotations:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", insertable = false, updatable = true, nullable = false)
private String m_firstName;
```

The `FIRST_NAME` column should **definitely** be ignored when generating SQL inserts. In other words, this sounds like a bug in TopLink Essentials which is developed in the GlassFish community. Actually, I think this issue is reported in [Issue #627](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=627) (*"Column annotation insertable=false only works when used with updatable=false"*). Sadly, it is not fixed so I'd suggest:

- to use `private String m_firstName = "my database default";` (yes, this is ugly) - OR -
- to change the persistence provider (for OpenJPA, Hibenate)

Answer (score 1):

try add somthing like this to your entity class.
This means exclude null property values in the Hibernate’s SQL

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "your_table")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
  dynamicInsert = true
)
public class YourClass{


}
```

Answer (score 1):

TopLink Essentials will only omit the column if you have both insertable and updateable = false.

This was fixed in EclipseLink, so you should consider upgrading.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without `@Basic(optional = true)`, because [that maps](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html#optional%28%29) to `NULLABLE` (which seems to be wrong in your case)?

> Defines whether the value of the field or property may be null.